# Getting subitems and values in JSON with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json, nested

I have a json file and i have to extract data in order to put them in an highcharts. The problem is that I didn't figured it out how to get "hours" values (00H00, etc.)

```
{
    "city_info": {
        "name": "Bordeaux",
        "country": "France",
     },
    "fcst_day_0": {
        "hourly_data":{
             "00H00" : {..."TMP2m": 11.2... }
             "01H00" : {..."TMP2m": 11.2... }
              .........
             "23H00" : {..."TMP2m": 11.2... }
     },
    "fcst_day_1": {
        "hourly_data":{
             "00H00" : {..."TMP2m": 11.2... }
             "01H00" : {..."TMP2m": 11.2... }
             .........
             "23H00" : {..."TMP2m": 11.2... }
        }
    },
     ....
}
```

Actually i try to display in a simple console log the values i want :

For having the days, a "for" is good enough. I can even have hourly_data.

```
function generateDataSet (myJson) {

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { 
        var hours = myJson['fcst_day_' + i].hourly_data;
        console.log (hours);
    }
```

But now i'm totally stuck. And would need some piece of advice as i just began learning jquery...
My next problem will be to integrate this in a chart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for like this:

```
function generateDataSet (myJson) {

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { 
        var hours = myJson['fcst_day_' + i].hourly_data;
        for(var a in hours) {
          console.log(a,hours[a]); // a is the key of the object, so your "00H00" etc,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! indeed it was really "simple"... but i wouldn't have found this by myself. it's just perfect ! Thanks a lot...

Comment: glad to be helpful! And welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted